# What is the corrected sample standard deviation when there is only one sample?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

What do we say about the corrected sample standard deviation when the sample size is one? Do we just assume it is 0? Is it even meaningful?

The usual equation seems to fall apart here because N - 1 is 0 and results in an (apparent?) division by 0.

Comment: Yes, it is undefined, since it is $0/0$.  Which makes sense, if you think about it.

Comment: Which "usual equation" do you mean? I define the standard deviation of $X$ as $\sqrt{E[(X-E[X])^2]}$.

Comment: @AlexBecker Kal is referring to the [*corrected* sample standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its undefined...the sample does not have an unbiased variance estimate, only a *very* biased estimate of 0.

Comment: Makes sense. A sample size of one is *very* biased indeed. There is simply no way to *correct* it/make it *unbiased*.